# How to Run two node app on single Ubuntu server having two public facing IP

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-virtual-machine

My case is, I would like to use Single VM to serve more then 2 Node App and all will use different Public facing IP.

---

Example 1:

Ubantu VM IP: 99.99.99.1
Additional IP1: 99.99.99.2
Additional IP1: 99.99.99.3

---

App1.Js -> 99.99.99.2:80 port -> this can be access by abc.mydomain.com
App2.Js -> 99.99.99.3:80 port -> this can be access by xyz.mydomain.com

---

This will allow me to use Single VM and multiple sites running on 80 ports.

OR may me other case like

Example 2:
VM1:99.99.99.2
App1.Js -> 99.99.99.2:81 port -> this can be access by abc.mydomain.com
App2.Js -> 99.99.99.2:82 port -> this can be access by xyz.mydomain.com

I would love to go with Example 1.

Hosting Environment will be Azure.

Thanks
Imran

Comment: Node apps shouldn't run on port 80. And if they did, it would be impossible for two distinct apps to run on the same port. You run each app on separate ports (say 3000, 4000, 5000) and then a lower-level process like Nginx redirects the IP/domains to each port (ex. domain1.com ---> port 3000, domain2.com ---> port 4000)

Comment: You might have more luck posting this on [SuperUser Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Not a node app expert but from the Azure perspective you should be able to accomplish what you are trying to do with an Azure Loadbalancer.

1. You can have multiple front-end Public IPs
2. You can use NAT rules to divert port traffic

Example 1, might work if you have multiple interfaces on VMs that way you can configure different apps to listen to different IP on port 80, not sure if that works with app node.  You can also use the NAT rules to divert port 80 to 3000, 4000 or 5000 on the local instance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I am working the same issue now. I believe you can. I am running Apache and have setup a proxy-redirect. The redirects point to the internal server location of my NODEJS. I have multiple conf files for Apache and each (domain) one has a proxy-redirect on them specifying the localhost (127.0.0.1) and the port. I can then setup each nodejs server to separate ports.

Comment: I have done this. The way that i done this is by setting up Apache on your VM instanace. In my case i use Google Cloud Platform - Compute Engine. Now in Apache setup either a http or https (ssl / port 443) config file for each domain that you wish to host. Now all you have to do is setup each NodeJS server to a diffrent port. If you are using Express JS, then this is very easy. Now that you have setup your port in NodeJS make sure that the path that Apache is looking for on the specific domain reflect.